# How to change the shape of selected tab in tab layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to make rounded selected tab. I have successfully made a rounded tab layout by setting its drawable background,but I want rounded particular selected tab.

Example screenshot

[image: just like same as in this image please see]

Comment: Create a `selector` drawable for tabs .

Comment: will you recommend any code for that?

Comment: If you want move this bubble with tab swipe then `selector` would not work individually . You need to look for custom pageStrip view for this.

Comment: OK thanks sir , i will try this

Comment: Have a look at [This](https://github.com/EzimetYusup/WormTabStrip) for reference. You will get the idea behind it .

Comment: yeah sir, this is definitely what i want , thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Selector` tag for 2 different state

1. State Selected
2. State Not Selected

   ```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/not_selected" android:state_selected="false"/>
   </selector>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution as it worked for me.

tab_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_active" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_tab"></item>
```

custom_tab.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"
android:textSize="@dimen/text_12" />
```

java code:

```
TextView tabOne=(TextView)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabOne.setText("TabTitleName");
tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.tab_selector, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
```